# Firebase Merge into single entity if Name matches in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Currently working on an simple shopping cart application.

When user clicks on the `Add To Cart` button I'm saving the product in DB as an array item.

When user trying to add multiple items of the same product, I wanted to group all products and increase the quantity and add it to DB.

Currently duplicates products of same name getting added.

Below is my code

```
  this.auth.uid.subscribe(uid => {
      if (uid) {
        const userCart = this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid);

        userCart.update({
          cart: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(product)
        });
      }
    })
```

I wanted to check if product name already exits, if so just update the quantity.

How do i achieve  it using Firebase please help

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `arrayUnion` operator to increment a value, as this operator checks for unique complete values.

What you *can* do is use the `increment` operator to increment a quantity field for each product:

```
const userCart = this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid);

userCart.update({
  [product]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
});
```

So with this you store each product as a separate field, and increment that. If a field for a product doesn't exist yet, this sets it to `1`.